# How can I use Korean font on jupyter notebook theme?

Tags: fonts, themes, jupyter-notebook

I wonder how can I use the Korean font 'D2Coding' on jupyter notebook.
I just installed the 'onedork' theme by jupytertheme

```
jt -t onedork -f roboto -fs 12
jt -t onedork -f D2Coding -fs 12
```

The first code is running but the second one is not running.
Maybe it is very easy question but I need your help.

Thank you very much in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes#monospace-fonts-code-cells) and [this issue](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes/issues/254), `jupyterthemes` currently only supports a specific list of fonts. Perhaps tracking that issue or commenting on it to add your support for the new feature would be useful.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. That's so useful. Thank you very much. Then is the font list updating continuously?